# Is it possible to efficiently convert PCollection list to PCollection (just values from the list)?

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-beam

I know it is possible using a ParDo function that yields elements from the list directly, but is there any other direct or more efficient method to do so?

Comment: Maybe you could add some context, some code of yours with what you tried and what's the difference between expected behaviour and actual behaviour in order for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Following the [official Documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/other/flatten/), you can use the `Flatten` method in order to merge PCollections. Examples are provided in [the Beam Programming Guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten).

```
# Flatten takes a tuple of PCollection objects.
# Returns a single PCollection that contains all of the elements in the PCollection objects in that tuple.

merged = (
    (pcoll1, pcoll2, pcoll3)
    # A list of tuples can be "piped" directly into a Flatten transform.
    | beam.Flatten())
```

Comment: PCollection list is different from tuple of different PCollections. It is a regular PCollection object.

Comment: @PartheshSoni what have you tried so far ?